# NDEF Capability Container decoding with NTAG 5 boost

Tags: ndef, nxp-microcontroller

I am currently working on an I2C communication between an i.MX6 (Android BSP) and a NTAG 5 boost component.

NTA5532 datasheet says :
*"According to NFC Forum Type 5 Tag Specification, EEPROM block 0 contains the Capability Container directly followed by the NDEF Message TLV."*

In fact, below is the user memory orgnisation of the NTAG 5 boost:

[image]

So I used TagInfo NXP's app to read the memory of the NTAG 5 component.

Here is what I get concerning NDEF Capability Container using this app:

[image]

How can I decode this block as NXP does in its application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following what says [this PDF from ST](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjSqbnFsrnvAhWZ8uAKHS5EDpsQFjADegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fapplication_note%2Fdm00442444-ndef-management-with-st25tvxxx-products-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw08OfSUxnvTJhyLUfgO4cP9) about NDEF management, *"The CC manages the information of an NFC Forum T5T"*, so the structure of this Capability Container is mainly common to all NFC Forum tags.

For more information about how to interpret the CC, see the previous pdf.